# Открытие определенной активности приложения?

Tags: android

Цель - открыть некоторую активность в одном приложении. Тестирую на переходе в настройки. Пытаюсь так

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings"});
Process h = p.start();
```

Почему ничего не происходит? Все же правильно! На тестируемом устройстве приложению предоставлены root права

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает стандартный способ запуска `Activity`, без использования команд "терминала"?

Comment: нужно открыть не настройки, а активность из инженерного меню. разве это можно выполнить без root

Comment: "инженерное меню" - это обычное приложение. Если вы знаете имя его Activity, то сможете открыть его обычным способом

Comment: Я знаю, это Engineer Mode.apk, системное приложение. Спасибо, сделайте ответом